# SharePoint 2013 - Customizing Search Result

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to customize the search result page according to a customized content its parent content type is article page.

I have created the customized content type (EnozomCT) and then created a result type that match the customized content type as in the screen shot

[image]

But when I start searching I have all the results with a result type web page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Set condition to Equals, why contains?
2. Change "Default Item" template with you custom template.
3. You have to recrawl if you change the content type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar problem with custom result type for a content type and actual results being displayed with out of box Microsoft PowerPoint or Word based display templates.

After changing the source of custom restult type to All sources from Documents, the custom defined result type is getting picked now.

Try to look at the source of Web page result type and ensure the same on your custom content type and see if it works for you